# Use of getElementByClassName over getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that Enumeration by ClassName can be used for multiple objects, and Enumeration by ID can be used for particular objects.

But is there any other specific difference between the two methods?

Comment: Read this: http://htmlcssjavascript.com/web/the-difference-between-javascripts-getelementbyid-and-getelementsbyname/

Comment: The first one gives back a NodeList, and the second one returns a single Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***getElementsByName:***

- This method returns the collection of elements whose name value is
  given by elementName (The name attribute value for an element.)
- This method is case sensitive.

***getElementById:***

- Returns the Element whose ID is given by elementId.
- If no such element exists, returns null.

*Note:* Behavior is not defined if there are more than one element has the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider also **Performance**.

Referring to this [link](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/25), it looks like  **getElementByClassName is faster**.

But it really depends on the specific page you are on, and the browser engine.

Comment: May I know the role of 'browser engine' in 'performance of classname over id'?